# How to select the top 2% of the values from a column, then write 1 if it is true and 0 when it is false?

Tags: linux, bash, columns

I have the following table:

```
CHR BP  SNP CM  AN1
1 15558213 rs2845371 0 -1.10837716961610
1 15558230 rs16981507 0 -1.13721847993853
1 15558586 rs5993924 0 -1.34239265871644
1 15563103 rs3016111 0 -1.61194237184708
```

I would like to select the highest 2% of the values in column 5, and when it is true, write 1 and when it is false, write 0.

I figured that I need to use the if...else command. However, I don't know how to define the first line (if col5= top2%)

```
if col5= top2%
then
awk '{$5=1 ; print ;}' file
else
awk '{$5=0 ; print ;}' $file
fi
```

I would be very grateful if you can direct me to the way to solve this.

Comment: Welcome, could you explain what you mean exactly with "top 2%"?

Comment: Sure! I want to select the highest values of all in column 5, and specifically the highest 2%. For example, we have these values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. 10 is in the top 10% of all values, so if my criteria would be 10%, I select 10 and write 1 instead of the actual number. Hope I explained it clearly!

Comment: I am not skilled enough with awk to do this in one pass, but I am guessing that you do not know the range of values before you begin? (e.g. you want top 2%, I am guessing you do not know "2% of what value" before hand. You can do this by finding the top values with awk if ($5 < highest) highest = $5 for example, this would find the max of $5. You could find the max and the next highest max.. but you want a percentage. Again, do you know the total range of $5 before hand? If not, you need to make two passes, one to find the range of $5, then you can calculate 2% and use awk similar to example.

Comment: I do not know the total range unfortunately. Great suggestion, I will try it, thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason we could not just put them in order highest to lowest and then just take the top 1 or 2.

Comment: No, it is also a good solution. I sorted the values from highest to lowest, but I still don't know how to select the top 2%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
  PASS==1{
    if (FNR==2){ min=max=$5; next }
    min=($5 < min ? $5 : min)
    max=($5 > max ? $5 : max)
    next
  }
  FNR==1{ threshold=(max - ((max - min) / 50)) }
  FNR>1 { $5=($5 >= threshold) }
  1
' PASS=1 file PASS=2 file
```

Read the input file in two passes.

First pass: Determine min and max value of the 5th field.
Second pass: Determine the threshold for the top 2% values on the first record. On any other records,
set the 5th field to `0` or `1` depending if the field is greater equal the threshold. Then print the record.

Output:

```
CHR BP  SNP CM  AN1
1 15558213 rs2845371 0 1
1 15558230 rs16981507 0 0
1 15558586 rs5993924 0 0
1 15563103 rs3016111 0 0
```

Comment: Great idea. Although using this approach I get 0 for each value in $5, no 1-s at all.

Comment: I get a threshold value of `-1.11845` and the first value is greater.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now, I just sorted the values from the highest to the lowest first.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but can you direct me how to do this if instead of 2% I want 1% and 0.5% of top values? Thank you so much!

Comment: Divide by `50` for 2% (100/2), `100` for 1% (100/1), `200` for 0.5% (100/0.5) ...

Answer (score -1):

Sort it first perhaps:

```
cat FileName.txt | sort -r -n -k5 | head
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Please note that your answer does not addresses the "write 1 if it is true and 0 when it is false" part of the OPs question; you may want to expand it in that respect.